# VBA USING TWO DIFFERENT RESULT USING countif VARIABLE

Tags: vba, variables, countif

Good Evening
I have a problem on VBA ​I have a variable as countif

```
Dim Y As Integer
Y = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Calc_Giac").Range("I11:EZ11"), ">0")
```

So If I use the variable in a formula

```
Range("B21").Formula = "=SumIF((I11:EZ11), "">0"") / (" & Y & ")"
```

The value is correct

But if use in a condition the result is the variable*-1

```
If ("(" & Y & ")" > 0) Then
Range("L19") = "(" & Y & ")"
Else
Range("L19") = "HELLO"
End If
```

Any Idea about it?

Comment: This is wrong: "(" & Y & ")" this is just a string, why don't you use : If y>0 then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You have a strange if-condition. Let's assume that `Y` has the value `3` as a result of your `CountIf`: "(" & Y & ")" resolves in a *String* `"(3)"`. After that, you check if the *string* `"(3)"` is greater that 0. That makes no sense. Try

```
If Y > 0 then
```

Second: You write the String `"(3)"` into a cell. Now depending on how the cell is formatted, either you have `"(3)"` (as String) in the cell (when the cell is formatted as Text), or Excel tries to convert the string `"(3)"` into a number. However, numbers in Excel that are entered with brackets are interpreted as negative numbers (try it by entering "(3") into a cell manually. Use:

```
Range("L19").Value = 3
```

However, within the formula, `=SumIF((I11:EZ11), "">0"") / (3)`, the `(3)` is just part of the calculation and the brackets tells Excel to evaluate anything within the brackets first before continuing the calculation. As `3` is already evaluated, there is nothing to do so the brackets are ignored.